# How to authenticate users either via HTTP Header or via parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing an API with Rails 4 and I'm trying to authenticate users.
Each user have a unique api_key and I want them to use it either by passing it through HTTP header or through params.

I use the authenticate_or_request_with_http_token method provides by Rails.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work when I pass the api_key through params:

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
   User.exists?(api_key: token) or User.exists?(api_key: params[:api_key])
end
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured out the answer for my question.
According to the doc on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html
for the HTTP Header authentication, if no token is found at all it returns nil.
So the test on the params won't be executed at all.

So I test the params before the HTTP header and let authenticate_or_request_with_http_token deal with the 401 unauthorized response.

```
unless  User.exists?(api_key: params[:api_key])
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    User.exists?(api_key: token)
  end
end
```